# How to set the python path for the bluemix CF Python Apps

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud

I deployed a Python Flask app to IBM Cloud (Bluemix). But python files in the inner directories of my app are not found by Bluemix: `[ImportError: No module named aciconsts ]`

unless I modify the path using `sys.path`. Is it possible to set `PYTHONPATH` to look for files in Bluemix CF Python App. In other words, are there environment variable like `PYTHONPATH` that can be set to look for python files in the app?

Comment: Can you show your project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add commands to your procfile.

Right now it most likely reads python yourappname.

Add a command before this line to add a directory to your Python path.

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

Should be said though, that dependencies should be installed with requirements.txt. Otherwise you risk running into staging errors and memory limits...